# phpMailer Not Working on web host

Tags: php

Can someone tell me why phpMailer not working on my webhost. I test my website locally with XAMMP and email sending with phpMailer is working correctly but when I upload my files to my webhost server it doesn't work. my script do not tell me any errors. neither my server error_log message is appended.

Is there any configuration that I may need to do on my server?

This is how am using phpMailer:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
//mailer function
function sendmail($mailFrom,$orgName,$toMail,$replyTo,$mailSugject,$mailBody){
    //Load composer's autoloader
require 'mailer/vendor/autoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);          
try {

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom($mailFrom, $orgName);
    $mail->addAddress($toMail);// Add a recipient
    $mail->addReplyTo($replyTo, $orgName);

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = $mailSugject;
    $mail->Body    = $mailBody;
    $mail->send();

    return array('Mailer' => 1,'msg' => 'Message has been sent');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    return array('Mailer' => $mail->ErrorInfo ,'msg' => 'Message could not be sent');
}

}
```

Comment: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/SMTP-Debugging

Comment: Because your hosting site doesn't allowing php `mail()` function. Try with `SMTP`

Comment: Please do some basic diagnostics! You don't enable debug mode, you don't verify return values, you don't even use the exception error message.